# onCLick list item Add 'active' Class in li and Remove from Siblings -- Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Default first li will be in active and if click on any li item Add Class 'active' and Remove Class from siblings

```js
public items = [{
    value: 'All',
  },
  {
    value: 'Photos',
  },
  {
    value: 'Video',
  },
];
```

```css
li .active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="nav-li">
  <ul>
    <li class="value" [value]="item.value"><a href="">{{item.value}}</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can save the clicked index in variable and toggle the class dynamically accordingly, as mentioned below -

```
<div class="nav-li">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
    [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === i}"
    [value]="item.value" 
    (click)='selectedItem = i;'>
      {{item.value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

selectedItem = 0;
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b4gcwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Suggestion -**  If not required try to iterate the `*ngFor` on `li` DOM element instead of `DIV` but doing so you are repeating `div, ul,li` elements for each iteration which is costly for the DOM prospective.

Comment: Thank you! @pardeep jain

Answer (score 2):

> .ts

```
    public items = [{
        value: 'All',
        active: 'active'
      },
      {
        value: 'Photos',
        active: ''
      },
      {
        value: 'Video',
        active: ''
      },
    ];
    
    changeStatus(index) {
      this.items = this.items.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        index === itemIndex ? item.active = 'active' : item.active = '';
        return item;
      })
    }
```

> .html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" class="nav-li">
  <ul>
    <li [class]="item.active" (click)="changeStatus(i)"  [value]="item.value"><a href="javascript:void(0);">{{item.value}}</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: how to display default fisrt li in active  @elonaire

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Please note that i have removed href from tag..
.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="nav-li">
    <ul>
        <li class="value" [ngClass]="getActiveClass(i)" [value]="item.value" 
           (click)="setActiveIndex(i)">
           <a>{{item.value}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

.ts

```
  var activeIndex;

  setActiveIndex(index) {
    this.activeIndex = index;
  }

  getActiveClass(i) {
    return this.activeIndex == i ? 'active' : '';
  }
```

.css

```
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Calling a method with binding in the template is never a good idea, each time change detection run this method will run.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Html**
    <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" class="nav-li">
      <ul>
        <li class="{{selectedIndex==i ? 'active':''}}" [value]="item.value"><a href="#" (click)="selectTag(i)">{{item.value}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    **Ts**
     selectTag(index){
        this.selectedIndex = index;
      }

**.Css**

.active {
  color: red;
}
```